# javascript DOM object inherit

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to define a event handler of one type of HTML object so that all the instances of this type of objects have this handler? for example, can I create a function func() as the onclick event handler of input text-fields so that all the input-fields have func() as its onclick event handler?

(it's just something like adding a function to the prototype of a native javascript object.)

Comment: Check this article: [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Instead, you can handle `onclick` for the `document`, then check if `e.target || e.srcElement` is an `<input>`.

This is how jQuery's [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) works.

Comment: Event delegation is definitely the way to go. This way, you don't pollute the prototype, and don't create tons of event handlers.

Comment: Do DOM objects inherit any common "superclass"?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, but it won't help.

Comment: The DOM prototype object behavior is inconsistent between implementations in my experience.  I'd suggest not fiddling with extending the prototype unless you have a lot of spare time on your hands.